# JavaScript - DOM nodeValue problem

Tags: javascript

Why the function `NodeValue__Two()` show `null`? To me, it should show the same thing as the function `NodeValue__One()`.

I have tested this on IE6.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function NodeValue__One() 
{
   alert(myNodeOne.childNodes(0).nodeValue);//This is OK   
}

function NodeValue__Two() 
{
   alert(document.all[6].nodeValue);//This is NOT OK
}
</script>

<p>This PARAGRAPH has two nodes, 
    <b id="myNodeOne">Node One Text</b>, and 
    <b id="myNodeTwo">Node Two Text</b>.
    <input id="txt1" type="text" value="Damn!!!" /> 
</p>

<button onclick="NodeValue__One();">Node Value 1</button></br>
<button onclick="NodeValue__Two();">Node Value 2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's good practice to use `document.getElementById("myNodeOne")` rather than just `myNodeOne`...

Comment: `childNodes(0)` is VBScript syntax, which only works in IE, and is only there due to Microsoft introducing it as a deliberate incompatibility in the 1990s. Use the JavaScript syntax `childNodes[0]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `All` array is an array of Elements.  Elements do not have a value in the nodeValue.

On the other hand `childNodes` will contain both Elements and TextNodes.

Its really hard to get the index of `All` correct since the number of actual elements listed in All can vary from what you are seeing in the HTML.  For example dispite there being no HEAD or TITLE Element present in the HTML text, they will be present in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches are deprecated and not safe. It would be better if you gave your elements unique identifiers and used `getElementById` function to find elements in the DOM:

```
var element = document.getElementById('id_of_element');
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason may be that you have erroneously assumed that "This Paragraph has two nodes".  It has at least six, including the three text nodes containing "This PARAGRAPH has two nodes,", ", and" and ".".

Comment: Nope, All doesn't contain text nodes at all.

Comment: Good point, I was blinded by the wording to the fact that this was wholly irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.all[6].text` this will give you `Node Two Text`